# Full Screen issue android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, android-fullscreen

I am having an issue with the app "Barcode Scanner", what is happening is when I go from my app, that I have built, to the barcode scanner, scan an item and return that item back to my app, I am shown my app in full screen mode but with the time bar overlaying the top navigation bar. Now to correct this I seem to have to go back to the barcode scanner and then press the back button to go back to my app.

My question is, why is is this happening and, if anyone has had this issue before, how do I fix it?